# terminal command not working in c# progra

Tags: c#, pdftk

I call a console program in a c# application but it's not working.

I'm trying to call pdf toolkit VIA c#.

When I run pdftk using command prompt, the output file (new.pdf) is created. When c# calls pdftk it doesn't error, but it doesn't work.

Am I calling it wrong in C# or something?

**C# Call:** (Not working)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pdfTKPath, pdftkArgs);
Console.Write(pdfTKPath + pdftkArgs);
Console.ReadLine();

// Here's the string that the console outputs.
// pdftk.exe C:\Users\name\Desktop\assignment1\assignment1\data\temp\test_cropped.pdf stamp C:\Users\name\Desktop\assignment1\assignment1\data\temp\test_footer.pdf output C:\Users\name\Desktop\assignment1\assignment1\data\temp\new.pdf
```

**CMD Prompt Call:** (Works Fine)

```
C:\Users\name>pdftk.exe c:\Users\name\Desktop\assignment1\assignment1\data\temp\test_cropped.pdf stamp c:\Users\name\Desktop\assignment1\assignment1\data\temp\test_footer.pdf output c:\Users\name\Desktop\assignment1\assignment1\data\temp\new.pdf
```

Comment: C:\Users\name\Desktop\assignment1\assignment1\bin\Debug

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\name>pdftk.exe
```

is wrong

Use the following one:

```
C:\Users\name\pdftk.exe
```

Also, did you escape

> \

symbol? It is required if you are hardcoding path in the app

Comment: The > is only there because it's a copy from a cmd prompt. 
Yes, all \ are escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe pdftk.exe is not in the path. Try to call the exe specifying it's full path.

Comment: Good idea, I added the full path, but no progress.

Answer (score 0):

firstly I would check if aprocess is created and if it has an error

```
var processo=System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pdfTKPath, pdftkArgs);
Console.Write("process created: "+processo.ExitCode);
```

Comment: I get an exception "Process must exit before requested information can be determined."

Comment: look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this wasn't working is that the processing that was happening with the prior method wasn't complete.

The method before this one uses ghost script to create a cropped PDF file. This method was evoked without ghost script completing the work. Therefore this method didn't think the files existed  yet (because they didn't). I set this method to wait 2 second before starting and it works fine. This allowed the previous method time to complete.